# How to properly use scrollbar in Caph Tizen Smart TV App?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to add a scrollbar to few components in Tizen TV app made with Caph. I have no idea how does the scrollbar looks in Tizen or how to properly add it.

Here's the example from the API reference. The docs aren't saying much.

```
var Scrollbar = caph.ui.base.component.Scrollbar;

 var horizontal = new Scrollbar({
   direction: Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL,
   currentThumbPosition: 300,
   maxThumbPosition: 600,
   sizeValue: 600,
   position: [50, 50, 0],
   on: {
       change: function(message) {
           console.log(message.detail);
       }
   }
});
```

Do I need a thumb element component or anything can be assigned as thumb? How will the scrollbar know if I'm adding a "thumb" as a child? Or do I add the scrollbar as a child to another component? I tried pretty much anything I could think of to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code and don't forget to include following css and js files before this code.

- caph-2.1.1-150302.min.css
- caph-2.1.1-150302.min.js
- caph.theme.stripe-2.1.1-150302.min.css
- caph.theme.stripe-2.1.1-150302.min.js

Above files can be found in **[Caph Full package](http://www.samsungdforum.com/AddLibrary/CaphSdkDownload)** available here for download.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Caph Scrollbar</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<!--Kindly keep an eye on how to include below css and js files.-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="$CAPH/2.1.1/caph-2.1.1-150302.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$CAPH/2.1.1/caph-2.1.1-150302.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="$CAPH/2.1.1/caph.theme.stripe-2.1.1-150302.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$CAPH/2.1.1/caph.theme.stripe-2.1.1-150302.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var Scrollbar = caph.require('stripe.ui.component.Scrollbar');

        caph.app.addScene('scrollScene', $class({
            $extends : caph.require('ui.base.Scene'),

            oncreate: function() {
                this.addChild(new Scrollbar({
                    direction: caph.ui.base.component.Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL,
                    currentThumbPosition: 150,
                    maxThumbPosition: 400,
                    sizeValue: 400,
                    step: 10,
                    position: [50, 30]
                }));

                this.addChild(new Scrollbar({
                    sizeValue: 300,
                    currentThumbPosition: 150,
                    maxThumbPosition: 300,
                    position: [50, 110]
                }));
            }
        })).run();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I did this. It finally shows the scrollbar, but I couldn't add any items to it. That's actually the part this is bit unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by adding items to it? Can you tell in detail.

Comment: Let's say I have a list of items placed in a box in the middle of the screen. And I want to add a scrollbar to it. The list won't be necessarily Caph list, just 20-30 items placed in small container.

Comment: ok. you mean to say, you have some content/list on that you want a caph scrollbar. Right?

Comment: Yes. For example the container is 400x400, has a longer list, and I want to scroll the list items inside of it.

Comment: As much I know, CAPH scrollbar can only be used for the main view, not for any subview which is inside the main view.

Comment: Ha, that's what I thought at first. So, now way around this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84935/discussion-between-srkushwaha-and-newbieonrails).